# Keeping layout consistent throughout several devices (SwiftUI)

Tags: layout, geometry, swiftui

I have a png background and I need to locate 5 texts on top of this png (see pic.). I am thinking of wrapping it all in a bundle of HStacks within one VStack. Something like this:

```
Vstack {
    HStack {
        Txt1
        Txt2
    }
    HStack {
        Txt3
    }
    HStack {
        Txt4
        Txt5
    }
}
```

The question is how do I adjust it all so it is precisely in the spots like on the example picture. And more importantly, how do I keep this setup consistent throughout several devices? I tried to run on several devices and texts are all over the place, jumping up and down, left and right. There's got to be some kind of a simple geometry-like solution or the way to pin down the Vstack dimensions to my png size. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Are you going to show that PNG resizable?

Comment: Yes, the png is resizable. It adjusts to the screen size perfectly. But the text is jumping from device to device. I used millions of paddings. I know that this is wrong, but I couldn't come up with anything else yet.